# Having issue requesting for a generated token

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am using the python wrapper for docusign `docusign-esign`.

I am trying to use the token a couple of ways hoping one of them will work. I have gone through the Docusign docs and examples; I am unsure where else to look for help on this.

I will link to docusign's code when posting snippets. So people who aren't familiar with the wrapper could also make sense of it.

I am using 2 methods [`request_jwt_application_token`](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/37245f757fe40228ff311d07f7fa0ea5877c15bd/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py#L704) and [`request_jwt_user_token`](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/37245f757fe40228ff311d07f7fa0ea5877c15bd/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py#L661).

```py
    results = api_client.request_jwt_application_token(
        DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY,
        DOCUSIGN_OAUTH_BASE_URL,
        private_key_bytes,
        TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS,
        scopes=(OAuth.SCOPE_SIGNATURE, OAuth.SCOPE_IMPERSONATION)
    )
```

```py
results:

{'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQgAAAABAAsADQAkAAAAYTNkZTI3MjMtMmUzYS00ZWUxLWE1NzktY2FjNjA1Z
DE3NDc5BwCAK89-QP_WSAgAgGvyjIP_1kgLAB8AAABodHRwczovL2FjY291bnQtZC5kb2N1c2lnbi5jb20vDAAkAAAAYTNkZTI3MjMtMmUzYS00ZWUxLWE1NzktY2FjNjA1ZDE3NDc5GAACAAAABQAAAB0AAAASAAEAAAAGAAAAand0
X2Jy.FK9nETujvSqQPyvE0LQZVuB-LrBHWUcmgFaqhGfBm9Wk39SlD41OohLRYGrM6SzXohjorSsDzRB9rHF9d9qmdKaj2ZXNGDBsTE3eRUGeYp-0cWRN3qYNQmgfdsqOTAslNiXQdNfgxsBFjaQtKag2f51MZ_xdvMW4iVjB1WMXFP
vf6BaEy5BJWzpdmd0JE5-8UvDhFV2wxLAGSc1d2JaxJbcFMnBt3-xQMmYtCgyJ5SAh9LxU_rAIt7AkoalPHILQjieAh4kupFeQiLJHSjX7o37K6DngG9I0iHXWspW_rMNOH-_70Um_iSPPNI_hnpJZKB3yDMkiuYcXZKFLEf1L7g',
 'data': None,
 'expires_in': '3600',
 'refresh_token': None,
 'scope': None,
 'token_type': 'Application'}
```

this is the closest I've been able to get when getting a token, however, when to use the token for getting user info [`api_client.get_user_info(token)`](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/37245f757fe40228ff311d07f7fa0ea5877c15bd/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py#L745)

I get

```
ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-DocuSign-Node': 'SE1DFE2', 'Content-Length': '87', 'Expires': '-1', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': 'e8af89bc-c18
4-45d7-8f9c-a7faff443006', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 22:56:50 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
HTTP response body: {"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"e8af89bc-c184-45d7-8f9c-a7faff443006"}
```

I looked up some solutions for this, but that didn't pan out.

I then tried to use

```py
    results = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
        DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY,
        DOCUSIGN_USERID,
        DOCUSIGN_OAUTH_BASE_URL,
        private_key_bytes,
        TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS,
        scopes=(OAuth.SCOPE_SIGNATURE, OAuth.SCOPE_IMPERSONATION)
    )
```

This didn't work at all. Fails to get a token.

```py
results:

Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA1DFE4', 'Content-Length': '27', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Co
ntent-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block; report=/clie
nt-errors/xss', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': 'b5d728bc-a442-4b35-bdb3-3026e64df334', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 23:12:49 GMT', 'X
-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2'})
HTTP response body: {"error":"invalid_request"}
```

I have gone over https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken and went through the troubleshooting.

Just wondering if anyone has some insight on what the issue may be.

Comment: How did you set your integration key? did you get an RSA key for it? when you obtained the token, did you get a consent screen from DocuSign? what url did you use for your API calls?

Comment: @InbarGazit **How did you set your integration key?** Through the developers portal API and Integration > Add Integration Key. **Did you get an RSA key for it?** Yes. **When you obtained the token, did you get a consent screen from DocuSign?** I Yes. I am able to make API calls through the sandbox account. **What url did you use for your API calls?** My base URL is `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi`

Comment: I'm confused, you said you are able to make API calls? just not using JWA tokens? is that what you're saying?

Comment: @InbarGazit I am able to make API calls. The token I am using is generated from `https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator`. I am now trying to generate the token through the API.

Comment: ok, I wonder again about your integration key. You said you got it using the developers portal API. Do you mean your sandbox account? did you then proceed to "go to admin" and go to the "API and keys" page to obtain it in there?

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes, the sandbox account through the admin part of it. I got the key which is a UUID and the status is Live.

Comment: did you check "Implicit Grant" ?

Comment: @InbarGazit I tried doing it with both Authorization Code Grant and Implicit Grant. Currently, it is on Implicit Grant.

Comment: Add for clarification. I am trying to do JWT grant according to https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication

Comment: ok, so just so we're clear, you are trying to get a JWT token, right?
how did you get the userId for the user you're trying to use?

Comment: also, I should clarify that the token you generated from our site is not a JWT token, so that may also be the source of confusion. You got it working with the more popular oauth flow, not the JSON token

Comment: Oh shit. I didn't even notice that. Well I need to get a Bearer token somehow so I can make API calls to Docusign. Is `/oauth/token` not the token I should be using?

Also, I get my userID when clicking on the top right corner the user avatar and copying the id looking something like `8634413`.

Comment: Oh boy. Have I been using the wrong id? Oh god. I found an ID in my Users settings under `API Username`. And.. it worked. Welp.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind marking this one "answered". I'll post an official answer just so it will not show in the search as "no answers" . thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195958/discussion-between-zyeek-and-inbar-gazit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a userId for the user you're trying to "impersonate" if you're using a JWT token. You can find that userId by logging to the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the solution (see the comments with the question):

1. Check that `Implicit Grant` is **not** checked for the Integration Key.
2. The `user Id` that will be impersonated is the `API Username` value from the **Users** section of the Administration tool. Don't confuse it with the short-form `Account Id` available near your name in the upper righthand corner of the DocuSign web tools.
3. Use the SDKs' `request_jwt_user_token` method to obtain an access token via the JWT Grant flow.